# Can't get filter() to return true when comparing href values

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a page with a couple of links including this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
```

And I have the following code:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.href == 'http://stackoverflow.com';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

For some reason the function in the filter never returns true. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```js
$('a').filter(function(){
  this.href == 'http://stackoverflow.com';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
```

Comment: At least debug it...

Comment: Because the Browser would add / to the URL and when comparing two strings you'll get it as false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will add a trailing slash `/` automatically at the end or the domain in the `url` in your anchor `href`, so it should be :

```
return this.href == 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
```

Hope this helps.

Take a look to **[Is trailing slash automagically added on click of home page URL in browser?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser)**

```js
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.href == 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link</a>
```

Comment: Huh really, thanks! So this.href refers to the property and not to the attribute?

Comment: Yes that true, glad  i could helps.